# Comparing value doesn't yield expected results

Tags: powershell, lync

I'm using the following code to bring back information from our Lync environment regarding the `RegistrarPool` that are associated to each user.

```
Get-CSUser | ? {
    $_.RegistrarPool -ne "SERVER-USER-POOL.example.com" -and
    $_.Enabled -eq $True
} | select SamAccountName, LineURI, RegistrarPool
```

My expectation would be the returned data would be users who aren't assigned to the "SERVER-USER-POOL.example.com", but that is not the case.

I can get the results I want by changing the `-ne` to `-notlike "SERVER-USER-POOL*"`.

Why isn't the `-ne` working in this case?  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this link.  Had to ask on another site since no responses here but wanted to share answer.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/nexthop/2011/03/21/get-csuser-and-get-csaduser-when-to-use-where-object-vs-filter-or-ldapfilter/

Answer (score 0):

After looking at a few things and looking at help

```
         get-help get-csuser -full
```

I came up with the following which also works.  Still not clear why my original didn't work.

```
Get-CSUser -filter  {
           RegistrarPool -ne "SERVER-USER-POOL.example.com" -and 
           Enabled -eq $True
           } | select SamAccountName, LineURI, RegistrarPool
```